# Dovecot is not locating messages in maildir, how to interpret debug log?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, dovecot

I'm setting up Postfix and Dovecot on Ubuntu Server 18.04.

Using Telnet to test the setup, I am able to log in with the desired email name, but the test is not finding any emails in the associated account. As far as I can tell, I've got the correct `mail_location` setting in my configuration files.

The test (from Dovecot Documentation's [TestInstallation](https://wiki.dovecot.org/TestInstallation) page) has the user log in, then run the following command:

```
b select inbox
```

The documentation test *example* shows the following as expected results if successful,

```
b select inbox
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft \*)] Flags permitted.
* 1 EXISTS
* 1 RECENT
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1106186941] UIDs valid
* OK [UIDNEXT 2] Predicted next UID
b OK [READ-WRITE] Select completed.
```

But I get the following

```
b select inbox
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft \*)] Flags permitted.
* 0 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1575837513] UIDs valid
* OK [UIDNEXT 1] Predicted next UID
b OK [READ-WRITE] Select completed (0.001 + 0.000 secs).
```

I have a good half dozen emails in `/var/mail/vhosts/adonax.com/phil/new`, including one sent and received just prior to doing this test (which I verified with a `cat` command)

Following is the debug log generated for the session.

First I log and run the command `a login "phil@adonax.com" "fakepassword"`

```
Dec 10 13:10:41 adonax dovecot: auth: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/auth
Dec 10 13:10:41 adonax dovecot: auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/auth/lib20_auth_var_expand_crypt.so
Dec 10 13:10:41 adonax dovecot: auth: Debug: Read auth token secret from /var/run/dovecot/auth-token-secret.dat
Dec 10 13:10:41 adonax dovecot: auth: Debug: passwd-file /etc/dovecot/users: Read 2 users in 0 secs
Dec 10 13:10:41 adonax dovecot: auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=10539)
```

So far so good, yes?

Second I run the test command `b select inbox` and get this result in the log file:

```
Dec 10 13:10:53 adonax dovecot: auth: Debug: client in: AUTH#0111#011PLAIN#011service=imap#011secured#011session=79iD8l+ZaJomADwBAADAPAA8kv/+k1+g#011lip=2600:3c01::f03c:92ff:fe93:5fa0#011rip=2600:3c01::f03c:92ff:fe93:5fa0#011lport=143#011rport=39528#011resp=AHBoaWxAYBRvbmFvbQBWtlNHmYB3b4LmN3Jk (previous base64 data may contain sensitive data)
Dec 10 13:10:53 adonax dovecot: auth: Debug: passwd-file(phil@adonax.com,2600:3c01::f03c:92ff:fe93:5fa0,<79iD8l+ZaJomADwBAADAPAA8kv/+k1+g>): lookup: user=phil@adonax.com file=/etc/dovecot/users
Dec 10 13:10:53 adonax dovecot: auth: Debug: client passdb out: OK#0111#011user=phil@adonax.com
Dec 10 13:10:53 adonax dovecot: auth: Debug: master in: REQUEST#0112679242753#01110539#0111#01118bfa959ad3d6d0c377ed53b2f0b3617#011session_pid=10541#011request_auth_token
Dec 10 13:10:53 adonax dovecot: auth: Debug: passwd-file(phil@adonax.com,2600:3c01::f03c:92ff:fe93:5fa0,<79iD8l+ZaJomADwBAADAPAA8kv/+k1+g>): lookup: user=phil@adonax.com file=/etc/dovecot/users
Dec 10 13:10:53 adonax dovecot: auth: Debug: master userdb out: USER#0112679242753#011phil@adonax.com#011uid=5000#011gid=5000#011home=/var/mail/vhosts/adonax.com/phil#011auth_token=04eb2747ef24bd23d6355aeb978ef361edbb48a3
Dec 10 13:10:53 adonax dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<phil@adonax.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=2600:3c01::f03c:92ff:fe93:5fa0, lip=2600:3c01::f03c:92ff:fe93:5fa0, mpid=10541, secured, session=<79iD8l+ZaJomADwBAADAPAA8kv/+k1+g>
```

Without fully understanding the above, I do see where what I think should be the correct "home" address is specified correctly as `home=/var/mail/vhosts/adonax.com/phil`
I can 'cd' to that directory, and it contains what I assume to be standard subdirectories:

```
root@adonax:~# ls -al /var/mail/vhosts/adonax.com/phil
total 24
drwxr-sr-x 6 vmail vmail 4096 Dec  8 12:38 .
drwxr-sr-x 3 vmail vmail 4096 Dec  1 19:45 ..
drwx--S--- 2 vmail vmail 4096 Dec  2 23:44 cur
drwx--S--- 2 vmail vmail 4096 Dec 10 12:25 new
drwx--S--- 2 vmail vmail 4096 Dec 10 12:25 tmp
drwx--S--- 3 vmail vmail 4096 Dec  8 12:38 var
```

Is this an issue somehow related to my session not engaging the `vmail` user? (If yes, I'll have to backtrack through the guide I'm using to set this up, as to how and why they create a general user specifically for handling email and if it has been done correctly.)

Is the issue maybe something to do with the configuration thinking that I'm making use of a database instead of a simple file with passwords? I see the term `userdb` in the following line.

```
Dec 10 13:10:53 adonax dovecot: auth: Debug: master userdb out: USER#0112679242753#011phil@adonax.com#011uid=5000#011gid=5000#011home=/var/mail/vhosts/adonax.com/phil#011auth_token=04eb2747ef24bd23d6355aeb978ef361edbb48a3
```

Could the fail be related to searching for "inbox" when either the search should be for something else or I've perhaps missed a step in not setting up an explicit "inbox" file folder?

Here are a few lines from `10-mail.conf` that were added (instructions to do so coming from the installation guide that I am using).

```
 mail_location = maildir:~/var/mail/vhosts/adonax.com/phil
 passdb {
   driver = passwd-file
   args = username_format=%u /etc/dovecot/users
 }
 userdb {
   driver = static
   args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
 }
```

I've created a long post here with a lot of info posted. I hope it is mostly pertinent to the question. I'm happy to add more to answer followup questions.

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

The `mail_location` setting had a ~ in the address that it shouldn't have had.

Based on that, it was looking in /root/var/mail/... instead of /var/mail/...

The Telnet test on port 143 now works.